# Diver jumps off a diving board

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

A diver leaves the end of a 4.0 m high diving board and strikes the water 1.3s
later, 3.0m beyond the end of the board. Considering the diver as a particle, determine: the magnitude of her initial velocity,

My workings.

horizontal => $v_x=d/t=3.0m/1.3m = 2.31$

vertical => $ S = S_0 + V_v t + 1/2at^2 $
$ 0 = 4m + V_v1.3 -4.915(1.3)^2$
$ 0 = 1.3V_v - 4.3m $
$ V_v = 3.31m/s $

so $ |V| = \sqrt{(3.31)^2 + 1.3^2}$

So my answer was $3.5m/s$, however this answer is not correct.

Comment: @ Suzu Hirose thanks for the edit, any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertical speed should be -4.06 m/s.
The acceleration is **negative**, vertical speed is **positive**, assuming the diver jumps up.

I'm assuming your mistake is due to a sign error.

x0 = x0 + vi*t + 0.5 * a * t^2

-3 = vi * t - 4.9 * 1.3^2

vi = (-4.9 * 1.3^2 + 3)/t

Comment: and that t that is being divided by in vi is 1.3?

Comment: so $-4.06m/s$ ...

Comment: 4.0 m/s was correct not negative

Comment: Well it will depend on how the question is asked, in this case, yes the magnitude of the velocity is 4m/s vertical.

Comment: Magnitude of a velocity is always positive.

Comment: how would I go about calculating the direction of her initial velocity angle?

Comment: arctan(vertical speed/horizontal speed), this would give you a positive angle, counter-clockwise.

Comment: @ Bloc97 so 3.31/2.31?

Comment: In this case, wouldn't it be arctan(4/2.31)?

Comment: nope 3.31/2.31 was correct, but thanks for your help